# CSS and HTML: HTML code wont take the style from the CSS

Tags: html, css

When im trying to apply CSS on my div id=four_sprint it doesnt work

HTML code:

```
<div class="select">
    <div id="four_sprint"> 
        <a href="four_sprint\index.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Show 4sprint</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works when im applying CSS in a style attribute in the HTML code

CSS code:

```
#four_sprint{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
#four_sprint:hover{
    color:orange;
}
```

The class="select" works but not the div id="

Comment: Please check that the `<a>` inside your `div` does not float. If it does, the surrounding `div` will have a height of `0` and thus, cannot be hovered.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code you're trying to style `a` tag not div. So use:

```
#four_sprint a{
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;

}
 #four_sprint a:hover{
color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   <style>
    #four_sprint a{
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;

    }
    #four_sprint:hover a{
        color:orange!important;
    }
</style>

<div class="select">

    <div id="four_sprint">
        <a href="four_sprint\index.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Show 4sprint</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```